# ffmpeg: Using with macos and swift

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to extract a thumbnail from the middle of a video. However, I am not sure if the issue lies within Swift or ffmpeg.

The following code compiles but produces nothing.

```
    let frameCount = GetVideoFrameCount(itemPath: itemPath)
    let framesIn = frameCount / 2
    let framesInStr = "\(framesIn)"

    let thumbnailTask: Process = Process()

    thumbnailTask.launchPath = self.ffmpegLaunchPath
    thumbnailTask.arguments = ["-ss", framesInStr, "-i", itemPath.absoluteString.removingPercentEncoding!, "-vf", "scale=-1:120", "-frames:v", "1", thumbnailPath]
    thumbnailTask.standardInput = FileHandle.nullDevice

    thumbnailTask.launch()
    thumbnailTask.waitUntilExit()

    let thumbnailStatus = thumbnailTask.terminationStatus
```

The "frameCount" variable does contain the number frames in the video. The Process "works" in that it doesn't crash, the .terminationStatus = 0 but no thumbnail .jpg is produced.

I have used the "-ss" option with **String(framesIn)**, **"\(framesIn)"**, I have changed the **frameCount** to an actual number (i.e., 10000), nothing. The "-ss" option **ONLY** works if I use **String(10000)** or any other number.

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you echo the command that is executed and share it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't because the Process does not spit out the command (at least not that I can see).

Even setting loglevels does not work. I tried "-nostats" and "-loglevel", "quiet" in the arguments list but ffmpeg still spits out all it's output.

I just tried using "-ss", "1000" and it worked. However, this still does not help me as to why passing in "(framesIn)" or String(framesIn) does not work.

Also, sometimes Process will be successful (i.e., .terminationStatus = 0) but no thumbnail is written to disk.